# how do I sort with child object in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to sort data of child object, remark :  they are not populated object.

My question is how to sort **f_fields** object with field : **f_position** that is in child object ?

**model.js**

```
var e_formSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        f_id: Number,
        f_name: String,

       f_fields: [{
            f_f_id:Number,
            f_position: Number,
            f_obligatory :Boolean,
            }]
    }

    , {collection: 'forms'});
```

**Data example**

```
{

    "f_id" : 3724,
    "f_name" : "form 1",

     "f_fields" : [ 
        {
            "f_f_id" : 64070,
            "f_position" : 5,
            "f_obligatory" : true,


        }, 
        {
            "f_f_id" : 64071,
            "f_position" : 6,
            "f_obligatory" : true
        }, 
        {
            "f_f_id" : 64204,
            "f_position" : 1,
            "f_obligatory" : true,
        }
    ],
}
```

**Result wanted**

```
{

    "f_id" : 3724,
    "f_name" : "form 1",

     "f_fields" : [ 
         {
            "f_f_id" : 64204,
            "f_position" : 1,
            "f_obligatory" : true,
        }

         {
            "f_f_id" : 64070,
            "f_position" : 5,
            "f_obligatory" : true,


        }, 
        {
            "f_f_id" : 64071,
            "f_position" : 6,
            "f_obligatory" : true
        }

    ],
}
```

I want to sort subobjects of **f_fields**, in there same object

I tried this code

```
  getForm:function (id, callback){
            var model = require("forms");


            //model
             model .find({f_id:3724}, function(err, forms) {


             forms.sort({'f_fields.f_position':1})



                 .exec(function(err, doc){
                    if (err) {

                        callback(err) ;

                    } else {


                        callback(doc) ;

                    }
                });
            });
        },
```

**Error**

```
has no method 'exec'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
  db.forms.aggregate(
    { $match: {
        f_id : 3724        }},

    // Expand the array into a stream of documents
    { $unwind: '$f_fields' },


    // Sort in descending order
    { $sort: {
        'f_fields.f_position':-1
    }}
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "f_id" : 3724,
            "f_name" : "form 1",
            "f_fields" : {
                "f_f_id" : 64204,
                "f_position" : 1,
                "f_obligatory" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "f_id" : 3724,
            "f_name" : "form 1",
            "f_fields" : {
                "f_f_id" : 64070,
                "f_position" : 5,
                "f_obligatory" : true,
            }
        },
       {
            "f_id" : 3724,
            "f_name" : "form 1",
            "f_fields" : {
                "f_f_id" : 64071,
                "f_position" : 6,
                "f_obligatory" : true,
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sam, but i  want in the return to have the 3 sorted sub objects in the same object "f_fields"

Comment: It is not possible directly sort nested array with mongoose. For this you can go with find query and then do sorting on the obtained result.

Comment: i tried annother script, like you mention, but it return an error, please have a look Sam, thank you.